# como convertir esta solución de for a recursiva ? (para C#)

Tags: c#

me piden encontrar el padre de la persona ingresada en consola dentro de una lista de datos ordenados tal que:

```
ID; Padre; Nombre
 1; -1;    Luzmira
 2;  1;    Sandra
 3;  2;    Priscilla
 4;  2;    Andres
 5;  3;    Ignacio
 6;  3;    Benjamin
 7;  3;    Martin
 8;  3;    Matias
 9;  4;    Isabel
10;  4;    Elena
```

y me gustaría saber como podría simplificar mi solución mediante la recursividad de ser posible.
esta es mi solución actual:

```
     public void imprimirPadre(string nom)//4
        {
            string[] nombre = new string[ListaDatos.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaDatos.Count;i++)
            {
                nombre[i] = ListaDatos[i].Nombre;
            }
            for (int d = 0;d<ListaDatos.Count;d++)
            {
                if (nombre[d].Contains(nom))
                {
                    for (int e = 0; e < ListaDatos.Count; e++)
                    {
                        if (ListaDatos[e].Id == ListaDatos[d].Padre)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Encontrado: " + ListaDatos[e].Nombre);
                        }

                            
                    }
                        
                }
            }
        }
```

Es decir, si ingreso Matías, debe devolver Priscila.

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Puedes dar formato con el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Y tiene que ser con arrays y for? Porque también puedes usar Linq;

Comment: ¿La recursividad es un requisito del ejercicio? porque de acuerdo con mi interpretación de la pregunta no es aplicable. Si ya tienes la lista en una colección llamada `ListaDatos`  ¿por qué creas un arreglo solo para los nombres? y si se trata de una lista ordenada ¿por qué haces una búsqueda del ID del padre? ¿no se supone que el valor de `padre` es la posición del arreglo donde se encuentra?